# Migrating to a bigger hard drive

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, boot, raid, bsod

My PC is a Dell Inspiron T3500, running a Xeon 3530, and 12GB DDR3 RAM.

I am currently running two WD Velociraptor drives, 300GB each, in RAID format, so it appears as one ~600GB hard drive on my PC. Recently I picked up a basic Seagate 2TB hard drive because I have so little room left on the two drives I've got in my PC currently. I decided to use Macrium Reflect to clone the two drives into one bootable situation with the new Seagate drive... and that's where this black hole of my patience and willingness to use technology starts... (I should mention my OS is Windows 7 Ultimate)

I first cloned the drive and everything went all too well. It cloned successfully with no issues, so I unplugged the two drives that are currently in my PC, disabled one of the HDD Sata ports via the BIOS and attempted to boot to my freshly cloned drive. It got to the Starting Windows splash screen, and right as those beautiful swirling dots started to appear, it threw me a BSOD, and faster than I could blink, it was gone. No biggie, I'll run the Macrium rescue media disc I created and attempt to fix the boot issues. So that's what I did "Repair Windows boot issues". It went through all of the steps, and failed to refresh/update the MBR... which... really is all I needed. Thanks Macrium. So tried again, no dice. No dice on the Windows startup repair, either, nor Seagate DiscWizard or anything else on the Ultimate Boot CD...

I have cloned it four different times now, three times via USB and an external case, and once via SATA internally. I've had no luck on any configuration. I've tried everything I can think of from boot repair programs to switching SATA performance modes.

Comment: before you clone the drive, activate the AHCI driver again: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/922976

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same issue when cloning Windows 7. Cloning XP was piece of cake but When installing Windows 7, it creates a hidden boot partition named System Reserved. When we clone Windows 7, we only clone the drive containing windows files not the hidden boot partition. To resolve this issue, I first installed Windows 7 on the new HDD and after the installation was completed, I then cloned other system into Windows partition of new HDD.

[image: System Reserve]

Don't know if you have tried anything like that. Hope that helps.

Comment: this could work, but he can simply clone the boot partition too then rebuild bcd records in accordance with the new partition scheme by using a system repair disc (if that's the problem)